# Sticky sessions in Lighttpd

Tags: load-balancing, lighttpd, sticky-sessions

I've read in 
http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs:ModProxyCore
that sticky sessions are not currently implemented in lighttpd. I'd like to know if it is possible to have sticky sessions using lighttpd as a loadbalancer. Perhaps implementing the sticky sessions using fastcgi or applying some patch?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to use Lighttpd as your load balancer?  You might be better off using something like HAproxy that supports source address hashing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:
http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/2117